# See last visited pages in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to see which pages were visited when? I want to see which pages where visited most recently. Can't find a way to see this in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics can show you which pages have been accessed in the last thirty minutes using their "real time" features.  Navigate to: Real-Time → Content → Pageviews

[image: real time pageviews]

Comment: Maybe he could get a daily report by mail from Behavior => Site Content => All pages just for date range yesterday or a very specific date range?